# JSF 2 Handling Data

Tags: jsf-2

I'm developing an app with JSF2 in Tomcat. Still pretty fresh to JSF I have a question which I guess is pretty simple to answer to someone who's got fairly good experience developing web aps and specifically in JSF 2. It's about the way one should store user's data during their interaction with the application. As it stands right now I am saving a lot of data in a session scoped managed bean (like collection of earlier pulled from database entities which themselves are linked to other entities)  and whenever a request is made the application will serve anyone of those objects stored in that collection. But I am worried that the session bean is becoming over bloated and don't know how much memory it is safe for a single session bean to consume. What I don't know is whwther when the app goes into production, and a lot of users log, is then the server gonna be ok to handle it. So I guess my question is as follows.

Is there any rule to go buy about storing, handlind and serving large amounts of users data that comes from the database:

1. Is it ok to do it my way (that is store a lot of stuff in a session scoped bean) so that with each request the app doesn't nee to query and retrieve the data from database. And it that's the case how to best load entities linked to an object stored in a list so they are not all loaded at once but only after the actual object is used to perform some operations before sending the data to the user.
2. Or should the app keep session beans fairly light (no lists of pre-pulled enities, objects etc) and instead make a trip to the database every time a larger piece of data is required, retrieve it and serve on the fly?
3. Or perhaps there's an entirely different method, preferred or recommended, to do this.

All suggestions and help are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not do the entity caching job by a JSF session scoped bean. You should delegate the entity caching job to the persistence layer and configure/finetune it over there. JPA and Hibernate for example have pretty good caching support. Here are some articles to read about it:

- [Javalobby - JPA Caching](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-caching)
- [EclipseLink Examples - JPA Caching](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching)
- [Hibernate Reference - Chapter 21 - Improving performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/performance.html)

A JSF session scoped bean should merely just contain session scoped data which is used in *every* request of the webapp throughout the entire browser session. For example, the logged-in user, the user preferences, the user language/locale, etcetera.

The (form) data should just be represented by a JSF request or view scoped bean. Just call the database on every fresh new request or view and do not worry about the costliness of the database trips in your JSF backing bean. Let the persistence layer worry about it.